# How to open React MaterialUI dropdown on click?

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, material-ui

I have a Material UI dropdown component and a label. How to open this dropdown clicking the label?

```
<label>Dash style</label>
<DropDownMenu
    value={this.props.seriesOptions.dashStyle}
    onChange={this.handleDashChange} >
    <MenuItem key={1} value={"Solid"} label="Solid" primaryText="Solid" />
    <MenuItem key={2} value={"ShortDash"} label="ShortDash" primaryText="ShortDash" />
    <MenuItem key={3} value={"ShortDot"} label="ShortDot" primaryText="ShortDot" />
</DropDownMenu>
```

Comment: You're talking about the default behavior. Did you import [`react-tap-event-plugin`](http://www.material-ui.com/#/get-started/installation)?

Comment: @LeeHanKyeol, No. How can it help me? Is there a onClick attribute that I need to add to the label?

Answer (score 3):

As I know, the `DropDownMenu` component don't have a property that let you control his state. However, you can use `Popover` with `Menu` component to do this.

You can write something like

```
        <label onClick={(event) => {
          this.setState({
            open: true,
            anchorEl: event.currentTarget,
          });
        }}>Dash style</label>
        <Popover
          open={this.state.open}
          anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl}
          anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'bottom'}}
          targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'top'}}
          onRequestClose={this.handleRequestClose}
          animation={PopoverAnimationVertical}
        >
          <Menu
            value={this.state.dashStyle}
            onChange={this.handleDashChange.bind(this)}
          >
            <MenuItem key={1} value="Solid" primaryText="Solid"/>
            <MenuItem key={2} value="ShortDash" primaryText="ShortDash"/>
            <MenuItem key={3} value="ShortDot" primaryText="ShortDot"/>
          </Menu>
        </Popover>
```

with these two components.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you. I used for now another workaround: absolutely positioned dropdown with a padding going over the label, so that the user has impression to click the label but actually it is the dropdown itself that is clicked.